# Component C1 Web Api CRUD using Java Script Sample produces error 404

Tags: c1-cms

No Response Found that Matches the requested URI. I followed the example exactly: http://www.composite.net/Products/Add-ons/All/Composite.AspNet.WebAPI/UserManual/Example-1-CRUD-Using-JavaScript

I received no compile errors. I did an iisreset after I copied the dll to the .\bin not that is should matter.

I think the datatype was never created.  There is no datatype in the console.

I'm just trying to get the sample working.  I even used the same variable names to make it easy. I'm on the latest version 5.  The odata sample works so I know the Web API packages is installed correctly.

Fiddler indicates there is no response for (website)/api/products

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem. When I compile the sample with bs 2015 I get no errors. However, when I copy the binary into the composite c1 bin folder, the class triggers a composite c1 build that does error with an assembly not found on the mvc assembly. The error is seen in the composite logs. So it makes sense it's not working. The work around was to copy the .cs file into code data folder- not a compiled assembly. This is demonstrated using the OData sample.